# Problem building SalesForce mobile app : Android

Tags: force.com, mobile, android, install

I created SalesForce Native/Hybrid app as in [this](http://www2.developerforce.com/mobile/getting-started/android) link.

Everything is fine but when I try to run the app by importing it into eclipse, it keeps on popping main activity with following error in logcat.

```
03-10 06:52:48.681: I/ClientManager:getRestClient(877): No account of type
com.salesforce.androisdk found
03-10 06:52:48.731: W/AccMgrCallback:run(877): android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: bind failure
03-10 06:52:48.731: W/AccMgrCallback:run(877):  at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:1612)
03-10 06:52:48.731: W/AccMgrCallback:run(877):  at android.accounts.AccountManager.access$400(AccountManager.java:140)
03-10 06:52:48.731: W/AccMgrCallback:run(877):  at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1458)
03-10 06:52:48.731: W/AccMgrCallback:run(877):  at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
03-10 06:52:48.731: W/AccMgrCallback:run(877):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
03-10 06:52:48.731: W/AccMgrCallback:run(877):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Same thing has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736245/authenticatorexception-bind-failure-on-avd) and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19407/no-account-of-type-com-salesforce-androisdk-found) but I could not understand the solution properly.

Even though I tried the solution provided in 1 of the links, it was not helpful.

Sample applications provided in SalesForce SDK work properly, don't know what's wrong with created applications.

Anybody please help me to get out of this.

TIA.

Comment: Hey Braj, hate to say it but I have to close this as it is a duplicate of the other question, I'll put a bounty on that that to draw some attention to it and hopefully we'll get an answer for you!

Comment: @LaceySnr - I tried both d answers provided in that link but they did not work... they say "u need to hv an actual device to run d app", then, how come sample app's provided in SalesForce SDK work on emulator? It's been a very long time... really I don't understand... Anyway, thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Yeah I know there's no great answer there yet but having two questions about the same thing just means there's two places that things have to be maintained, and one may get an answer and one may not which doesn't help people down the road. Hopefully something will get added now some more attention has been drawn to it.

Comment: @LaceySnr - I completely understand ur concern. Lets hope for d best :)

Comment: Hey @Braj, check out the other question. There's a new answer on there now which looks like a good candidate for a fix!